# R Shiny DT with radio-buttons breaks when adding language option

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, dt

I am trying to develop a sort of form through a shiny app, the idea is that the user fills a specific field (a zoning of medical-development priority) about many geographical places (french districts). Thus I think DT is the best option. I don't want to make the column `editable` because I want the user to choose between 4 specific values (the idea of the form is to reduce the free text to be cleaned afterward).

I started to work with the example of YiHui https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/
As I work for french users I tried to add an option to customize language to french, but the entire logic broke, I don't know why.

Here is a reprex : (simply comment the line with `language = list(...` to make it work).

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:5])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month.abb[i], m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 'tirp', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE
                     ,language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/French.json')
                     ),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
)
```

Here is my sessionInfo()

with R 3.6.0

> sessioninfo::session_info()
>   - Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
>     setting  value
>   version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
>   os       Windows 10 x64
>   system   x86_64, mingw32
>   ui       RStudio
>   language (EN)
>   collate  French_France.1252
>   ctype    French_France.1252
>   tz       Europe/Paris
>   date     2019-06-26
>
> - Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>     package     * version date       lib source
>     assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     crosstalk     1.0.0   2016-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     digest        0.6.19  2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     DT          * 0.7.1   2019-06-26 [1] Github (rstudio/DT@c6fd864)
>     htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     htmlwidgets   1.3     2018-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     httpuv        1.5.1   2019-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     later         0.8.0   2019-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     mime          0.7     2019-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     packrat       0.5.0   2018-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     promises      1.0.1   2018-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     shiny       * 1.3.2   2019-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     sourcetools   0.1.7   2018-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
>     yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)

I also tried with R 3.5.2 but I have the save issue.

When I click some radio-buttons I should see :

```
List of 12
 $ Jan: chr "1"
 $ Feb: chr "2"
 $ Mar: NULL
 $ Apr: NULL
 $ May: NULL
 $ Jun: NULL
 $ Jul: NULL
 $ Aug: NULL
 $ Sep: NULL
 $ Oct: NULL
 $ Nov: NULL
 $ Dec: NULL
```

Instead it says NULL, I can't find any explicit error.

```
List of 12
 $ Jan: NULL
 $ Feb: NULL
 $ Mar: NULL
 $ Apr: NULL
 $ May: NULL
 $ Jun: NULL
 $ Jul: NULL
 $ Aug: NULL
 $ Sep: NULL
 $ Oct: NULL
 $ Nov: NULL
 $ Dec: NULL
```

What is the problem with the language option in DT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain but this works by adding a `setTimeout`:

```
  callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                  var $this = $(this.node());
                  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                  $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
                });
                Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                setTimeout(function(){
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());
                },0);")
```

---

## EDIT

The above worked for me but I set `dom = ftirp`. That doesn't work with `tirp`. Here is another solution:

```
output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
  m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
  options = list(dom = 'tirp', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                 initComplete = JS("function(settings,json){
                                     var table = settings.oInstance.api();
                                     Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                                     Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());}")
                 ,language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/French.json')
  ),
  callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                  var $this = $(this.node());
                  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                  $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
                });")
)
```

Comment: @phileas Very strange. Indeed that doesn't work like that, but this works if you set `dom = 'ftirp'`.

Comment: @phileas See my edit, I added another solution which seems to work better.

Comment: So the key was to set the Shiny.unbindAll & Shiny.bindAll after initComplete rather that as a callback ?